# SDWebImage Downloading Multiple Images (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimage, sdwebimage

For my iPhone app, I am trying to use SDWebImage to download multiple images from a list of links. The problem is after the images are downloaded, I don't know how to find out which image was downloaded from what link.

For example, I have a list of 25 image links. I use the following code for each link, where downloader is an instance of SDWebImageDownloader:

```
downloader = [SDWebImageDownloader downloaderWithURL:url delegate:self];
```

The above code starts the downloading process and once the image is downloaded, the following code is called:

```
- (void)imageDownloader:(SDWebImageDownloader *)downloader didFinishWithImage:(UIImage *)image
```

From the above method, I can see the list of all my 25 images, but they are not in order (obviously). I was wondering if there is a way to keep a track of images and their corresponding image links. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImageDownloader has an URL property, which is the corresponding image link:

```
- (void)imageDownloader:(SDWebImageDownloader *)downloader didFinishWithImage:(UIImage *)image 
{
    NSString* url = downloader.url;   
}
```